# women (wife) have a bigger influence regarding shalom bais

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, shalom-bayit

**the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe [writes](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/maharyatz/ig/14/5132/index.htm)**

> ועלי' להשתדל לסבב סיבובים שיהי' שלום בית, אשר הוא דבר המסור **ע"פ תורה** לאשה יותר מלאיש
>   **that according to Torah** making peace in the house is more on the wife than on the husband

the Lubavitcher Rebbe [writes](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/10/3042/index.htm)

> שלום בית ... וברובא דרובא בענינים דשלום בית תלוי יותר בהאשה מאשר בהאיש...
>   that most of the time it depends more on the wife than on the husband

the Rambam [writes](http://www.chabad.org/952889/) (first about the woman and then the men)

> This is the custom of holy and pure **Jewish women** and men in their marriages. And these ways will make their marriage pleasant and praiseworthy.

**what might be the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe's source?**

Comment: Perhaps experience? Why do you expect there to be a textual source?

Comment: @DoubleAA the words ע"פ תורה

Comment: I'm assuming that he may have gotten this from the story of Sarah wanting to oust Yishma'el and Hagar. It seems Avraham didn't want this, and G-d says, "Listen to all that Sarah tells you." I think a Midrash or a commentary alludes to the idea that women have a sense of seeing the future in ways that men can't. In this situation, they may have mentioned that Sarah viewed Yishmael's living home as impeding on Shalom Bayit.

Comment: @DanF please explain more, i do not see any connection between Yishmael and Shalom Bayit, (in this case is it not Avrohom who is making the shalom bayit by being mevater to his wife ("ובודאי משים לב למרז"ל אשר נשים דעתם קלה והאשה דמעתה מצוי' ושערי דמעות לא ננעלו ובמילא בענינים כמו אלו **יש על הבעל לוותר** במילי דארעא עד כמה שאפשר"  from http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/8/2454/index.htm , http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/4/1141/index.htm , http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/4/1154/index.htm , http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/5/1257/index.htm ,

Comment: and http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/6/1661/index.htm ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the three sources you quoted, I think that all MY readers would benefit from seeing the context of the quotes, which will help answer the question.

For the first source (the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe), he continues by quoting the Passuk in Mishlei 14:1:

> חַכְמוֹת נָשִׁים בָּנְתָה בֵיתָהּ וְאִוֶּלֶת בְּיָדֶיהָ תֶהֶרְסֶנּוּ
>
> Every wise woman buildeth her house; But the foolish plucketh it down with her hands. (JPS)

(in his words "וכתי' חכמות כו' בנתה ביתה עפ"י התורה והמצוה.")

Perhaps this is his source right here, that it is the woman's job to build the Bayis, as in, keep the Shalom Bayis, which works especially well with Hashem having given women "Binah Yeseirah" (see [here](http://www.chabad.org.il/ParashotArticles/Item.asp?CategoryID=78&ArticleID=265) also).  This is slightly unlikely, however, as he seems to be adding another point by bringing this Passuk.

The second source, the Lubavitcher Rebbe is clearly speaking from practical experience, as evidenced by his wording and the context of his statement in a letter.  Please read the letter in the link, where he is offering advice to a couple to help resolve some Shalom Bayis issue.

The third source, [Rambam Ishus 15:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952889/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Fifteen.htm), is most clear.  He says:

> וכן צוו על האשה שתהיה **מכבדת את בעלה ביותר מדאי ויהיה עליה מורא ממנו ותעשה כל מעשיה על פיו**. **ויהיה בעיניה כמו שר או מלך מהלכת בתאות לבו ומרחקת כל מה שישנא**. וזה דרך בנות ישראל ובני ישראל הקדושים והטהורים בזיווגן. ובדרכים אלו יהיה ישובן נאה ומשובח:
>
> And similarly, they commanded a woman to honor her husband exceedingly and to be in awe of him. She should carry out all her deeds according to his directives, considering him to be an officer or a king. She should follow the desires of his heart and shun everything that he disdains. This is the custom of holy and pure Jewish women and men in their marriages. And these ways will make their marriage pleasant and praiseworthy.

Rambam (after listing the requirements of the man to his wife, see Halacha 19 there) lists the requirements of the woman towards her husband, including how she should listen to him etc. etc. is clearly focusing on the wife, and as a result, she is listed first.

This would also serve as a source for "the Torah putting the burden of Shalom Bayis on the wife". Rambam certainly sounds like that when you read his words above (see the bolded terms, where Rambam assumes it is her responsibility to "follow the desires of his heart, and shun everything he disdains).

Feedback encouraged as usual, but I feel like this is at the very least an adequate answer to the question.

Comment: Maybe related https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.17a.16

Comment: @hazoriz interesting source.